# PDFJS: how to render pages and load data on request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, pdf.js

I would like to show pdf files in my web app, PDFJS is working fine but I would like to load the pages on scrolling. I found PDFJS supports rendering on loading. I dont want to load whole document at a time. user clicks on next page get next page data and render.

I would like show pages on request?

How to render pages on request using PDFJS?

Comment: I assume, that this is not possible. PDF stores vital information at the end of files, so you have to load it completely before starting to render. (Not accounting for the case, where one PDF is specially prepared as compound of several others.)

Comment: I believe some PDF libraries perform an on-demand rendering by extracting and returning a page as a PNG.

Comment: @Boldewyn PDF.js using range transport (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/2719) so I think it is possible by doing similar like range transport.

Comment: @veritasetratio generating images causing heavy load.

Comment: @user1834809 yes, in that case it can work. I'm curious, if there will be a solution.